# Flowchart: Assess Project Completion, Communication Skills, check eligibility, calculate overall score, determine performance rating

Tags: flowchart

Consider a employee performance evaluation system with the following criteria: Each employee is evaluated based on two factors: Project Completion Rate (0-100) and Communication Skills (0-10). If an employee's Project Completion Rate is below 60 or Communication Skills are below 5, they are considered to have poor performance. If both Project Completion Rate and Communication Skills are 80 or higher, the employee is recognized as having excellent performance. The final decision for performance rating is made based on an overall assessment, where Project Completion Rate contributes 70% and Communication Skills contribute 30%. To receive a top rating, an employee must have an overall assessment score of 75 or higher.

A simple diagram flowchart with box shape

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.